# How to access my Vue app outside of vue not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I have a standard app using vue CLI3 with Babel support. I'm trying to trigger a function within one of my components in my app. My current solution works fine in all browsers except IE11.

I have the following in my main.js

```
//import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = true;

window.myapp= new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),

}).$mount('#app');
```

Somewhere else on my page I have the following code executed upon a user's click.

```
myapp.$children[0].$children[0].loadMyFuntion();
```

This works great for all browsers except for IE11 :(

I've also tried stuffing it inside Vue.prototype.$myapp however IE11 seems to not have my variable populated. It shows up in FF or anything chromium.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I have no answer  as for why it doesn't work. But this looks really hacky. Do you use Vuex? There has to be a better, cleaner and more reliable way to do this. Can you explain, in short, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Try to declare the variable before load the vue app, when loading the Vue app check it and then assign value.

Comment: How do you use `myapp`? It also shows not defined on my side in other browsers. I use `myapp` in App.vue. You could check [my demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-j1h0k). It could be better if you share a simple sample to reproduce the issue. And is there any error in console in IE? Besides, I found [a thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/call-method-in-app-vue-from-window-global-scope/65273) which had the same issue with yours, you could refer to it for more information.